# Integrate Wordpress CMS in CakePHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I'm trying to integrate Wordpress in CakePHP 2.6.1 [to use it as a CMS](http://techthat.net/2010/05/19/using-wordpress-as-a-website-backend/) for my end users.
I'm including the required file to access wordpress functions: `wp-blog-header.php`.

As CakePHP only allows to include files located inside CakePHP I placed the wordpress intallation inside `app/Vendor/wordpress` and now I'm trying to import the necesary file in my `AppController` in this way:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'wordpress'.DS.'wp-blog-header');
```

But it seems there's some functions conflict as I'm getting this error from CakePHP:

> Error: Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in /home/todopeta/alvarotrigo/pruebas/cakephp/lib/Cake/basics.php:581)
>   File: /home/todopeta/alvarotrigo/pruebas/cakephp/app/Vendor/wordpress/wp-includes/l10n.php
>   Line: 163

Has anybody integrated wordpress in CakePHP before?

What's the way to go for it?

I've seen [it seems to be possible with other PHP MVC frameworksk such as Laravel](http://grossi.io/2014/working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together/).
Is CakePHP more restrictive in this respect?

Comment: So you are decorating your cake with cowpat, that doesn't sound very tasty... I'd advise not trying to mix the two, it's a receipe for a catastrophe, if you really need to use WP for whatever reason, run it separated from your CakePHP app. https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+and+cakephp

Comment: @ndm but CakePHP doesn't allow to include files from outside itself. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's php, you can include as much as you want. The issue is that you probably will have to have include tons of files and do some bootstrapping or initialization for the WP scripts as well which then ends up in a pretty fugly piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the WP data by creating a WP plugin for CakePHP and add a model for each of the WP tables and read the data via CakePHP.

Your linked article does the same but it uses the WP_Query class and further down Corcel which seems to be a mix between the Eloquent ORM and WP. I would not go that path and use the CakePHP ORM.

I can guarantee you that everything else is going to become a pain in the rear thanks to the fugly WP code and architecture.

If you try to use the WP code inside CakePHP like you've tried this will become super painful, time consuming and probably never work right without some really really fugly code.

If you need only parts from WP consider creating a WP plugin and embedd the WP content via an iframe in your page. AFAIK WP got a json API as well these days, you could try to read the data via that API as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a nightmare and end up with a massive mess of code with this approach.

Instead, why not try and use a CakePHP CMS system, for example:

https://croogo.org/

Comment: Sorry, but clients still preferring the wordpress one (and so do I). I was not expecting it to be such a big deal, as it doesn't seem to be with [other PHP frameworks](http://grossi.io/2014/working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together/).

Comment: I don't envy you on this one Alvaro, I agree the WP back end has a nice design, but it really is going to be a hell of a job to integrate the two. I suppose you could create a WP install for back end users and build a CakePHP app which uses the same db - so it is populated by wp and read by cake - but I shudder at the thought!