# Using Wordpress functions from inside CakePHP 3, redeclare issue

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp, namespaces

With this project I've decided to make the jump up to Cake 3.0.  I simply have one page in my Cake App that needs to be able to access Wordpress functions.

I have the latest version of WP installed in the root/public_html folder of my site, and it's available at www.mysite.com.  I have Cake 3.0 installed so it's accessible at www.mysite.com/cake.

My goal is to have the home page of the Cake App check if a Wordpress user is logged in.  If so I'll let the user continue to the rest of the app, and if not I'll redirect the user back to the main Wordpress site to login.

By including the wp-load.php file from Wordpress I get a redeclare error from a collision on a function named __().  I'm pretty sure I can fix this with namespaces, but I'm unfamiliar with the use of such so I'm here looking for a little guidance.  Here's the code I have in cake/src/Pages/home.ctp:

```
<?php
namespace WPint;
use WPint;
require( '/home/mysite/public_html/wp-load.php' );
$user = wp_get_current_user();
?>
```

It's very simplistic but I think you can get the point as to what my goal is.  If someone could help point me in the right direction, or let me know if this is even feasible, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrate Wordpress CMS in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398788/integrate-wordpress-cms-in-cakephp)

Comment: I've read that answer.  I don't think it entirely does what I want.  In fact...I've done just that previously...but am still unable to access wp functions, which are needed to match the password hashing if using a wp model to login users.